# Codeigniter select query with bindings

Tags: codeigniter, binding

I have a big problem, what i can't solve. In codeigniter i created a model, who done this:

```
public function listazas($mettol, $mennyit, $feltetel)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM vicc ORDER BY ? DESC LIMIT ?,?";
        $query = $this->db->query($query, array($feltetel, $mettol, $mennyit));

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

In the controller i use it:

```
   $viccek = $this->index_model->listazas(0, 10, "ertekeles");

   $this->load->view('index/index', array(
       'viccek' => $viccek
   ));
```

And here the sql don't do the order by section... why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's because you're doing a `ORDER BY 'column'` instead of `ORDER BY column`.

You'll have to do a replace on current function with:

```
public function listazas($mettol, $mennyit, $feltetel)
{
    $feltetel = $this->db->escape_like_str($feltetel);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM vicc ORDER BY {$feltetel} DESC LIMIT ?,?";
    $query = $this->db->query($query, array($mettol, $mennyit));

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Basicly your `query()` escaped the `$feltetel` with `''` around it, making it act like a string instead of a column name.

For a query as simple as this one, you can do it easier through [Active Records](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select).

You could also try to troubleshoot this yourself by running a `echo $this->db->last_query();` after the `$this->db->query()` and compare the result.
Then you would had noticed the `''` after `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Replace your function with given above.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (name, age, groupname)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$this-> db-> query($sql,array('codeigniter', 35, 'Group 1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**its so easy** have a look at this example just the model only in the controller you just have to call the method with these parameters for more detail solution you can ask me

```
public function read_all($limit,$start){
    $this->db->select('*');        
    $this->db->from('postes');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);    
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result_array();
}
```