# CodeIgniter - query binding "order by"

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter, I'm binding my query to a set of variables.

```
$q        = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name=? ORDER BY ?";
$name     = $this->input->get("name");
$order_by = $this->input->get("order_by");
$this->db->query($q, array($name, $order_by));
```

But "order_by" isn't working properly. I've searched through, but I'm not sure how to "sanitize" the "order by" clause.

Answer (score 2):

try this way,

```
$order_by_arr = array('name', 'age', 'date');
if (!in_array($order_by, $order_by_arr)) {
  $order_by = 'name';
}

// now u can use $order_by. its safe :) ...
```

Comment: Hm. Makes sense, but seems kind of hacky!

Comment: shouldn't it be if(in_array) instead of if(!in_array)?

Comment: yea. its up to u. i just said an idea. :)

Comment: just tried it and does work wonderfully. :) love to hear more thoughts from others too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$order_by = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->get("order_by"));
$q        = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name=? ORDER BY {$order_by}";
$name     = $this->input->get("name");
$this->db->query($q, array($name));
```

refer this link, this suits your requirement best.

[Query Binding in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652423/codeigniter-select-query-with-bindings)

Comment: That does not sanitize the value of $order_by - does not prevent SQL injection on the order_by variable.

Comment: I think it is secure at an extent. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Comment: I run the above query via URL as follows - http://myapp/get_table?name=table_name&order_by=id - now, I can do a following SQL injection http://myapp/get_table?name=table_name&order_by=id;select * from users - and the injected query will return results - so I don't think it's secure.